# Getting Xcode to register build setting or xib changes

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm losing more time on Xcode issues than on learning the SDK.

When I change build settings, or even when I rewrite the Xib file, Xcode often doesn't correctly register the changes until I quit and restart it. Sometimes, I even have to do a clean all.

Is there a script or command one can do from within Xcode which kicks it awake and makes it smell the coffee?

Is there a decent guide to Xcode somewhere?

Ed.

Comment: Is the issue that IB isn't automatically saving changes when you build, or that you have saved changes that Xcode isn't noticing?  How is the nib managed in the project -- is it a direct project member, or is it in a "blue folder?"

Comment: The Xib is a direct project member. 

It's a general irritation with refreshing Xcode every time I change -and save- interface layout or modify build settings.  Back in the old days, I remember there used to be issues on Unix when updating the make file itself rather than a source file ... a manual clean was required. Xcode seems to have some new variant of this old bug.

Comment: Like cdespinosa says, xib files generally are managed and saved by Interface Builder (IB). I just tried opening a xib as a source file, changed menu item Copy to Cccopy then pressed the Build & Go button (without saving first) and Cccopy showed up as expected. If an executable is runnign already, you will have to stop and start it, of course. Are you sure you're running the latest version of Xcode for your platform? Mine's 3.1.3 (haven't switched to Snow Leopard yet).